# Android WebView - orientation change after form submitted with POST

Tags: android, post, webview

I have developed android application. It opens HTML page which contains a POST form with one field. Here is it's HTML:

```
<form method="post">
   <input name="key" type="text"> <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have followed suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640501/how-to-fix-rotation-on-webview-for-android-phones) to properly store/restore WebView state while device orientation change and it works properly in most cases except following:

Step 1. When I run this application

Step 2. Populate form

Step 3. Submit form

[Step 4](https://24f32520-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/ashvedandroiddevelopment/android-webview---orientation-change-after-form-submitted-with-post/step4.png?attachauth=ANoY7cq3NwXDMjqwts21ZCfuMFpOv32Nx6slIy2zDUpryMBcvnC8UpLs00czc8QGXcYYSAYSq_k7EqwJpNvhhc14V9gMtHcxE1khWUqmHC2HhNdlfoPz822eGkYJCixbY_FWziBd-LKp0PStBXvW0_fr-5E4uXZybYdHAulDphFEzIV5PqpnjK5m6FITfX9KQqWYu5BBTcXBC-TBb1Rblzsl4nSBq-x11Mkm8wIwG9Qq4gruPx90ByqlSH92ef_JvrYGTnaYbmX-gU0xRzSEZwvDxH7O2ELdCGrymbSpDMT78Yx9YUR7TKC6eooywBGKEVENgY1WT7Bz&attredirects=0). Change orientation of my device

I get **Web Page Not available** massage. Instead of just display restored WebView.
Am I missing something in my activity or in some configs to make WebView properly change orientation after form was submitted with POST ?

Thanks in Advance:

P.S.

Here is are methods of my activity

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else {
        loadPage();
    }
}

private void loadPage() {
    String url = preferences.getString(PrefsActivity.WOW_APP_URL, PrefsActivity.DEFAULT_URL);
    webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.101:8080/wow66/orientation.jsp");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView.saveState(savedInstanceState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Next time you could simply upload your picture to Stackoverflow